# ToDoList for a Self-Configuring Models

Tags: anylogic, webinar

First, Thanks for the webinar from Mr. Schumann "How to Build a True Digital Twin with Self-Configuring Models Using the Material Handling Library"
I am a beginner for using Anylogic and have a question about this model.
I don't really understand the collection MachinesToDo, the products runs sequentially(source->M1->M2->M3->sink) or randomly? Or How to make product run sequentially all the time(No need to use AGV).

**Or how to build a Todolist for the elements from a population of agent in a metierial handling system.**

It would be greatful if I could get an answer from someone :)
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi @Mengzhang, welcome to StackOverflow. This place works best for you if you ask very specific questions, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. Your question if far too broad and would need a full lecture to tell you all about it. I suggest you read up here to learn how to ask great questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Treat us as very busy colleagues that are happy to help. The more effort you put into your question, the more likely you will get a good, fast reply :)

Answer (score 0):

`MachinesToDo` is a LinkedList collection. You will need to learn some Java basics (such as what a LinkedList is) to understand the model, it is fairly advanced (as I mention in the video).

Comment: thanks for the answer, I'm going to study more basics